# How to make a hole in a Crescent without deforming?

Tags: mesh, boolean-modifier

I have a crescent which I want to make a hole through it, but when I use the boolean modifier it warps it. Is there any way to have a hole without the deformity?

[image: crescent pict]

Comment: How did you make the  crescent? The ability to make a clean hole depends heavily on the underlying topology (which is why Booleans don't work well).

Comment: I used a tutorial on youtube where he used a path then increase its depth to achieve the crescent shape, i exported the shape and import it back so that the bolean modifier would show up when selecting the modifiers.

Comment: @Ranierz: since you are a beginner i would suggest you provide your blend file so we don't have to ask several questions until we have the informations we need to know in order to be able to help you. You can upload your blend file here by opening https://blend-exchange.com/ and following instructions.